# Know which page the user is browsing in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

I would like to create a web page which is a main page that has one iframe whose content does not come from the same host as the main page but I would like to know which page the user is currently browsing in the iframe.

For example, I have a main page with a button bound with an Javascript event and an iframe that load content from a site like google.

A user can navigate the content in iframe as he wants but when the button in the main page is clicked, the current url in the iframe must be popped up.

I already tried it but since the same origin policy always applies, an error like this
**Permission denied to access property 'location'** occurs.
I do know that it makes sense according to SOP but I really need to do it.
I would like to know if there is some hack that can do the trick or I have to admit the
restriction and design my app the other way.

Answer (score 1):

If there was such a trick, it would make browser security invalid and expose privacy issues. These things are there for a reason.

You can disable this for YOURSELF, but bypassing it for others is evil.

See:

[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy)